# FSelector Package- Error in Formula

Tags: r

I am new to R, though I have taken a basic programming course. I would like to use the oneR function in the FSelector package, but continue to receive the error ("Error: unexpected input in "df1<- oneR(play˜") for the formula argument. The data is a dataframe.

Please review my code and advise. It is much appreciated. I am looking forward to using the package.

Thanks!

Kay

```
data = read.csv(file.choose())
names(data)<- c("outlook","temperature","humidity","windy","play")
library(FSelector)
df1<- oneR(play˜., data)
print(df1)
```

Data:

```
outlook temperature humidity windy play
1     sunny         hot     high FALSE    N
2     sunny         hot     high  TRUE    N
3  overcast         hot     high FALSE    Y
4     rainy        mild     high FALSE    Y
5     rainy        cool   normal FALSE    Y
6     rainy        cool   normal  TRUE N   
7  overcast        cool   normal  TRUE Y   
8     sunny        mild     high FALSE  N  
9     sunny        cool   normal FALSE Y   
10    rainy        mild   normal FALSE Y   
11    sunny        mild   normal  TRUE Y   
12 overcast        mild     high  TRUE Y   
13 overcast         hot   normal FALSE Y   
14    rainy        mild     high  TRUE    N
```

Comment: You could also try the OneR package from CRAN: CRAN.R-project.org/package=OneR. I am the developer of that package and would be interested in the result with your data set.